# Meteor.js keeps getting me Errors and waits for change

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, canvas, svg

after I add this library: https://www.amcharts.com/javascript-maps/

```
$ meteor
```

gives me this Errors:

> import/ammap/ammap/plugins/dataloader/examples/gantt_json.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/dataloader/examples/gauge_json.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/dataloader/examples/map_json.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/dataloader/examples/map_json_external_function.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for
>      you)
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/dataloader/examples/pie_csv.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/dataloader/examples/pie_json.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/dataloader/examples/serial2_json.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/dataloader/examples/serial_csv.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/dataloader/examples/serial_json.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/dataloader/examples/serial_with_dynamic_graphs.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for
>      you)
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/dataloader/examples/stock_csv_data_and_events.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for
>      you)
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/dataloader/examples/stock_csv_progressbar.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/export/examples/advanced.html:1: Expected one of: , , 
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/export/examples/funnel.html:1: Expected one of: , , 
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/export/examples/gantt.html:1: Expected one of: , , 
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/export/examples/gauge.html:1: Expected one of: , , 
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/export/examples/index.html:1: Expected one of: , , 
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/export/examples/map.html:1: Expected one of: , , 
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/export/examples/pie1.html:1: Expected one of: , , 
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/export/examples/pie2.html:1: Expected one of: , , 
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/export/examples/pie3.html:1: Expected one of: , , 
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/export/examples/pie4.html:1: Expected one of: , , 
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/export/examples/radar.html:1: Expected one of: , , 
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/export/examples/serial1.html:1: Expected one of: , , 
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/export/examples/serial2.html:1: Expected one of: , , 
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/export/examples/serial3.html:1: Expected one of: , , 
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/export/examples/stock.html:1: Expected one of: , , 
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/export/examples/xy.html:1: Expected one of: , , 
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/responsive/examples/funnel.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/responsive/examples/gantt.html:1: Expected one of: , , 
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/responsive/examples/gauge.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/responsive/examples/index.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/responsive/examples/map.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/responsive/examples/pie1.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/responsive/examples/pie2.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/responsive/examples/pie3.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/responsive/examples/radar.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/responsive/examples/serial1.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/responsive/examples/serial2.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/responsive/examples/serial3.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/responsive/examples/stock.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/ammap/plugins/responsive/examples/xy.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/_CSS_animations.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/_JSON_animationsAlongLines.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/_JSON_changingProjections.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/_JSON_curvedLines.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/_JSON_developerMode.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/_JSON_drillDownMap.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/_JSON_flightRoutes.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/_JSON_groupedCountries.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/_JSON_heatMap.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/_JSON_mapWithPatterns.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/_JSON_singleCountryMap.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/_JSON_translatedCountryNames.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/_JSON_worldCapitals.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/_JSON_zoomingToCountries.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/_SVG_filters.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/_exporting_to_multiple_formats.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/_usingThemes.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/animationsAlongLines.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/changingProjections.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/developerMode.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/drillDownMap.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/flightRoutes.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/groupedCountries.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/heatMap.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/mapWithBubbles.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/mapWithPatterns.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/singleCountryMap.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/worldCapitals.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/samples/zoomingToCountries.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
>      import/ammap/index.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)

Meteor recomended this:

`meteor npm install --save canvas amcharts3`

but nothing has changed since I do that!

still same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the only `3` `js` and `css` files ( the important ones ) into `'[project-root]/public'` then it worked nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

you are going to have to remove the issues with the library, like removing DOCTYPE. or you can try [this package](https://atmospherejs.com/em0ney/amcharts)

Comment: and with package : **ReferenceError: AmCharts is not defined** -> this error keep showing

Comment: I just imported this package into [the todos project](https://github.com/meteor/todos) and it worked fine. how did you add it and import it?

Comment: i download the only 3 js and css files ( the impportant ones ) into [project-root]/public it work fine now tnx